# How do I add a char variable to a string?

Tags: c++, string, char

I am making a Hangman game as a first C++ project, and I need to keep a bank of all the letters that the player has already used. Right after the player guesses a letter, I need to add it to the `guessed` bank. The guess is a `char` variable defined globally, as is the `guessed` variable. I have tried to do it like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

char guess;
string guessed;

int main() {
    cin >> guess;
    guessed->push_back(guess);
}
```

However that doesn't work. I have also tried using the `+=` operator, and I get an error

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'std::__cxx11::string [0]' {aka 
'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> [0]'}
```

I am guessing something is wrong with my variable types, however this is my very first C++ project and I can't exactly figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Add `#include <string>`.

Comment: Wouldn't `guessed.push_back(guess)` be the correct syntax?

Comment: Is this compiling correctly?  The `guessed->` should be generating an error since `std::string` is not a pointer and the `operator->` is for use with pointers.

Comment: just use **guessed.push_back(guess)** its working

Comment: `string[0]`? Something doesn't add up. Show a real [mcve].

Comment: No, `guessed.push_back(guess);` returns: `error: request for member 'push_back' in 'guessed', which is of non-class type 'char 
[0]'`

Comment: XY Answer: Assuming English, you an make an array of 26 `bool`s. Initialize the array to false. When a letter is guessed, set the matching array element to `true`.

Comment: Now `char[0]`? This is not the real code you're testing!! Once more, present a [mcve].

Comment: Side note: Avoid global variables. They do not scale well. As programs gain complexity it is very hard to be able to trace who changed the global variable, why, and when. Any function can change the value at any time, so a bug could be lurking anywhere.But if you pass the variable around as a parameter you have a much clearer path and significantly simpler debugging..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than making a bank of the characters been used, I think it would be better to just keep them by the index 0-25.

You could create a array of 26 `bool`s. If the user enters `a`, then the corresponded `bool`, or index `0` would be set `true`. Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cctype> // for std::toupper(char c)

int main()
{
    char guess;
    std::array<bool, 26> guessed;
    std::cout << "Take a guess!\n";
    std::cin >> guess;
    guess = std::toupper(guess); // Make it to uppercase so you don't need to check the case
    if(guessed[guess - 'A'])
    {
        std::cout << "You already guessed it!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        guessed[guess - 'A'] = true;
    }
}
```

With this way, you don't need any `.find(char)` functions, although it's not a large list to go through.

You can also easily print all guessed letters:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < guessed.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(guessed[i])
        {
            std::cout << static_cast<char>(i + 'A') << ", ";
        }
    }
```

Gameplay wise, this prints letters in alphabetic order, instead of chronological, which I think is easier to find the letter's you haven't guessed yet.

Comment: This works very well. I believe @Nissim Levy suggested this, but thanks for the example. One thing though? What would I do if I just wanted to do lowercase? In other words, how would these mechanics work without the use of the `toupper()` function? Also, you misspelled touuper where you put: `guess = std::topper(guess);`

Comment: You are right, I misspelled it. There’s also `std::tolower` which work basically the same, except you would change `guessed[guess - ‘A’]` to `guessed[guess - ‘a’]`. The reason I would include `toupper`or `tolower` is because you wouldn’t know if the user would guess `a` then decides to guess `A` for some reason. You might also want to put them in a `if(std::isalpha(guess))` to check if they even guessed an alphabetic letter.

Comment: Yes, If this was very official, that would make sense, however I am just doing it for fun.

Answer (score 1):

for your purpose I think the best will be to use `std::set< char >`.
This will hold no duplicates and return an answer in O(log n) time.

or actually because it's a small limited range, you can actually use binary array of length 26

an example, as you requested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  char guess;
  std::set<char> lettersBank;
  std::cout << "Plz enter your letter guess:";
  std::cin >> guess;
  lettersBank.insert(guess);
  
  // check if some letter is already inside the set:
  char checkLetter = 'd';
  if(lettersBank.find(checkLetter) != lettersBank.end())
    std::cout << "you already guessed this letter" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Could you give me an example of what that would look like in the code?

Comment: Also look at `std::unordered_set`. For something as simple as `char` the look up will be very close to O(1)

Comment: Actually, for small datasets (remember this is likely to be 26 elements max), the benefits of a set (particularly an unordered one) aren't really worth all the indirection and tree (or bucket) management. Linear search in a 26-element `char` array is absolutely trivial. It's the most self-documenting code, though, I'll give you that (and probably what I'd use unless I were tuning!)

Comment: Asteroid's right. Cache and the CPU's ability to predict and process ahead means the array approach's O(N) time complexity will almost certainly be faster than anything you can do with a smarter algorithm until you get into the hundreds or thousands of elements..